# Scrollbar is cutting off content extjs

Tags: extjs, scroll, scrollbar, scrollable

When a scrollbar is added to a container, the horizontal scrollbar cuts off the bottom content of the container (only the first time the toggle button is pressed).

Attached is the fiddle. Please note that I am ultimately trying to create a class that can be extended by a view, and the superclass's purpose is to dynamically add scrollbars to specific containers. For sake of an example, I created a simplified fiddle:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2e3c

or the code is here:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'panel',
            width:300,
            height: 300,
            title: 'test',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            items: [
                {
                xtype: 'container',
               flex: 7,
                style: {
                    'border': '2px solid black'
                }
            },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                flex: 3,
                itemId: 'lowerContainer',
                style: {
                    'border': '2px solid red'
                },
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'field1'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'field2'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'field3'
                }]
            }
            ],
            bbar: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Toggle Scrolling',
                enableToggle: true,
                listeners: {
                    toggle: function(btn, pressed){
                        var lowerContainer = this.up('panel').down('#lowerContainer');
                        if (pressed){
                            lowerContainer.setScrollable({
                                y: 'scroll'
                            })
                        }
                        else {
                            lowerContainer.setScrollable(false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see weirdness like that, try to update the component layout
lowerContainer.updateLayout();

[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2e6n)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Nikos Js! I appreciate it!

That certainly fixed my example, but unfortunately did not resolve the issue in my superclass (I must have missed something in creating the example). However, I found another way to resolve the issue. It turned out that when I set y to "scroll" using the setScrollable method, I was setting the scrollbar on the outer div tag of the container. However, the inner container div tag held the content that was overflowing the container. In turn, I tried placing the scrollbar on the inner div tag. I implemented another strategy:

```
lowerContainer.setScrollable({
    y: 'scroll',
    x: true,
    element: lowerContainer.el.dom.querySelector('div[data-ref="innerCt"]')
});
```